# Conditions to make a map surjective.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are three finite dimensional CW complexes and let $[X,Y]$ denote the homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to $Y$. The we have map $$\phi: [X,Y] \times [Y,Z] \to [X,Z]$$
given by just composing homotopy classes. My question is there some result which says when this map is surjective.

It is clear that this need not always be the case since the triviality of $Y$ would make the left hand side trivial even though the right hand side may be non trivial. Also I have heard that this is surjective if we put $Y=S^n$ and $Z=K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ where $n$ is dimension of $X$. So I am hoping that these fall out from some general result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The map you describe in your question is

\begin{align*}
\phi : [X, Y]\times[Y, Z] &\to [X, Z]\\
([\alpha], [\beta]) &\mapsto [\beta\circ\alpha].
\end{align*}

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional CW complex and $Z$ a CW complex. By the cellular approximation theorem, any continuous map $f : X \to Z$ is homotopic to a cellular map $\hat{f} : X \to Z$, in particular, $\hat{f}(X) \subseteq Z^{(n)}$ where $Z^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$-skeleton of $Z$. So there is a map $g : X \to Z^{(n)}$ satisfying $\hat{f} = i\circ g$ where $i : Z^{(n)} \to Z$ denotes the inclusion. Letting $Y = Z^{(n)}$, we see that for any $[f] \in [X, Z]$ we have $[f] = [\hat{f}] = [i\circ g] = \phi([g], [i])$. Therefore $\phi$ is surjective.

The example you gave, namely $Y = S^n$ and $Z = K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$, is a special case of the example above. To see this, we will build a CW complex $Z$ which is a $K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$ and has $S^n$ as its $n$-skeleton.

Recall that $S^n$ has first non-trivial homotopy group $\pi_n(S^n) = \mathbb{Z}$ and that it has non-trivial higher homotopy groups (unless $n = 0, 1$). One can glue on cells of dimension at least $n + 2$ to obtain a space $Z$ with $\pi_i(Z) = 0$ for $i > n$. As $Z$ is obtained from $S^n$ by adding only cells of dimension at least $(n + 2)$, we have $Z^{(n+1)} = Z^{(n)} = S^n$. By the cellular approximation theorem, for $i \leq n$, $\pi_i(Z) = \pi_i(Z^{(n+1)}) = \pi_i(S^n)$. Therefore $Z$ has only one non-zero homotopy group, namely $\pi_n(Z) = \mathbb{Z}$, so $Z = K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$.